# FORTRAN executables: heap maxed out

Tags: linux, virtual-memory, fortran

I am trying to run a FORTRAN program on stampede (xsede machine). The error message I am getting is 'heap maxed out'. I think it has something to do with virtual memory allocation. So I use the following command to allocate more threads to my process
 "export OMP_NUM_THREADS=100"
But still I am getting the same error message. Can anyone help me to solve this?
Thanks!